# Duplicates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I am using Google sheets and I am trying to concatenate multiple column A values in Column C, when and if Column B has a duplicate:

Sample data:

```
     Column A    Column B           Column C
  1    1247       Santa Fe          1250/1150
  2    1250       Santa Fe          1247/1150
  3    1258       North Shore       1354
  4    1341       Hogan             1255
  5    1255       Hogan             1341
  6    1354       North Shore       1258
  7    1150       Santa Fe          1247/1250
```

Here, Column C needs to have multiple concatenated values of A,  corresponding to the duplicates in column B.

Comment: Why is the first *North Shore* 1354 but the second *North Shore* is 1258/1354? This contradicts the other two-item count of *Hogan* where the first is 1255 and the second is 1341.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C1:

```
=JOIN("/",FILTER($A$1:$A$7,$B$1:$B$7=B1,ROW($B$1:$B$7)<>ROW(B1)))
```

Drag fill down.